# How can I read /dev/inputs/js0 data in 8bytes?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, input, device

I have a gamepad (Buffalo iBuffalo Classic USB Gampe for PC) and want to read its input value when I press the buttons.

I am using,

```
Ubuntu 16.04
Kernel 4.15 
64 bit
```

In my code,

```
import sys
pipe = open("/dev/input/js0", "r", encoding="utf-8")
msg = []
while 1:
    for char in pipe.read(1):
        msg += [ord(char)]
        if len(msg) == 8:
            print(msg)
            msg = []
```

However, I am getting unicodeDecodeError `'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc8 in position 0: invalid continuation byte`. So I used `codec` module,

```
import codec
pipe = codec.open("/dev/input/js0", "r", encoding="utf-8")
```

But I am still getting same error. I also tried to read different mode, `rb`. How can I read this input values and having it as 8btye values and in hexa format(ex.001c)

Comment: You're reading in utf-8? Does the joystick actually produce utf-8 characters, or does it provide bytes? You probably want to read the bytes raw rather than utf-8.

Comment: Use the mode `'rb'` to open the device.

Comment: @Tanktalus I guess it is supposed to produce bytes.